# Maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ of a non-discrete valuation ring of rank one satisfies $\mathfrak{m}^{2}=\mathfrak{m}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, valuation-theory

I have a problem when reading Gabber's *Almost Ring Theory*.

> Let $V$ be a non-discrete valuation ring of rank one. Does its maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ satisfy $\mathfrak{m}^{2}=\mathfrak{m}$?

Here is my attempt. Take $\sum x_{i}y_{j}\in\mathfrak{m}^{2}$, $x_{i},y_{j}\in\mathfrak{m}$. Then $v(\sum x_{i}y_{j})\leq\max\{v(x_{i})v(y_{j}),...\}$, so that $v(\sum x_{i}y_{j})\leq 1$ and $\sum x_{i}y_{j}\in\mathfrak{m}$. However, this can not prove that $\mathfrak{m}\subset \mathfrak{m}^{2}$.

Comment: Hint: translate this in to a problem about the value group. What does it mean that the valuation is non-discrete? Can there be a minimum positive valuation for an element of the maximal ideal?

Answer (score 3):

Let $\Gamma$ be the value group of $(V,v)$. Denote the valuation field by $K$.

Suppose that there is an element $x\in V$ admitting the minimal nonzero valuation $v_{0}=v(x)$. Since the rank of $V$ is $1$, we can identify $\Gamma\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q}$ as $\mathbb{Q}$.
For any element $y\in V$, if we put $v(y)$ in the additive group $\Gamma\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q}$,
then we can write it as $v(y)=mv_{0}+r,$ where $m\in\mathbb{Z}, 0\leq r<v_{0}$. Consider the element $y\cdot x^{-m}$, it has valuation strictly smaller than $v_{0}$, thus it must be an unit (Notice that, by our notation, an unit has valuation $1$, but under the isomorphism $\Gamma\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q}\simeq \mathbb{Q}$, it corresponds to $0\in\mathbb{Q}$).
This shows that $\Gamma$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, which is a contradiction to the fact that $V$ is non-discrete!

For each element $x\in\mathfrak{m}$, its valuation $v(x)<1$ is not minimal in $\Gamma$. So we can take $y\in \mathfrak{m}$ such that $v(y)<v(x)$, then $xy^{-1}$ must also be an element in $\mathfrak{m}$, which proves that $\mathfrak{m}=\mathfrak{m}^{2}$.

Comment: If $\Gamma$ is $\mathbb{R}$, then $\mathbb{R}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}$ still isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @ToneyLeung No. But if $\Gamma=\mathbb{R}$, then the valuation ring is not of rank one.

Comment: You view $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ as a multiplicative group ($v(xy)=v(x)v(y)$ as in your question), and it must be an abelian group!

Comment: Oh, I forgot that $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is an abelian group, which implies that it is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. But how to prove that $\mathbb{R}_{>0}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q}\cong \mathbb{Q}$? I tried to use universial property, but failed.

Comment: @ToneyLeung Are you sure when $\Gamma=\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ this valuation is of rank $1$? The isomorphism you mentioned doesn't hold.

Comment: So what is your definition of valuation of rank 1?  In my view, an additive valuation of rank 1 means $\Gamma$ is isomorphic to some subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$, and a multiplicative valuation of rank 1 means $\Gamma$ is isomorphic to some subgroup of $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$.

Comment: Ah, I use the so-called "rational rank" and I think the one you use is the convex rank. If we follow your definition, then we can obtain the result that $\Gamma\subset\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ doesn't contain a minimal element similarly, and the following proof is almost the same.